# Is it possible to use the Android NDK for Android Wear apps?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, wear-os

I look forward to create an android wear application with some 3d content. That for I like to reuse libraries written in C/C++. Is it generally possible to create an Wear APP with the NDK? Do you know about any primer or example code which does so?

Comment: Yes, it's like for regular Android, since there is only ARM at this time on physical Android Wear device, you don't have to target MIPS or x86.

Comment: Cool! That's good. Do you know about an example somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried it, and can confirm that is possible to call native code through JNI on Android Wear.  It works exactly the same as it does on regular Android.